# Room Database Many to Many reletionship

Tags: android, android-room

### Problem Description

Inside Room Database I have 3 tables: `Portfolio`, `Coin`, and `Transaction`

**Portfolio Entity**

```
@Entity
data class PortfolioEntity(

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val portfolioId: Long,

    val name: String,
)
```

**Coin Entity**

```
@Entity
data class CoinEntity(

    @PrimaryKey
    val coinId: String
)
```

**Transaction Entity**

```
@Entity
data class TransactionEntity(

    @PrimaryKey
    val transactionId: String,

    val portfolioId: Long,
    val coinId: String
)
```

In my case, each instance of the `Portfolio` entity corresponds to zero or more instances of the `Coin` entity, and vice-versa, so this is many to many relationships, so I define a cross-reference entity like

```
@Entity(primaryKeys = ["portfolioId", "coinId"]
)
data class PortfolioWithCoinsCrossRef(
    val portfolioId: Long,
    val coinId: String
)
```

Also, each instance of the `Coin` entity corresponds to zero or more instances of the `Transaction` entity, and vice-versa, so this is again many to many relationships, so another cross-reference entity will look like:

```
@Entity(primaryKeys = ["portfolioId", "coinId", "transactionId"]
)
data class CoinWithTransactionsCrossRef(
    val portfolioId: Long,
    val coinId: String,
    val transactionId: Long
)
```

So no the classes which are representing this relationship

```
data class CoinWithTransactions(
    @Embedded val coin: CoinEntity,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "coinId",
        entityColumn = "transactionId",
        associateBy = Junction(CoinWithTransactionsCrossRef::class)
    )
    val transactions: List<TransactionEntity>
)

data class PortfolioWithCoinsAndTransactions(
    @Embedded val portfolio: PortfolioEntity,
    @Relation(
        entity = CoinEntity::class,
        parentColumn = "portfolioId",
        entityColumn = "coinId",
        associateBy = Junction(PortfolioWithCoinsCrossRef::class)
    )
    val coins: List<CoinWithTransactions>
)
```

So my query method looks like

```
 @Transaction
 @Query("SELECT * FROM portfolios")
 suspend fun getAllPortfoliosWithCoinsAndTransactions(): List<PortfolioWithCoinsAndTransactions>
```

### Question

The problem is that when I am calling the method `getAllPortfoliosWithCoinsAndTransactions` it returns the following data

The query function returns the result below when Only 1 transaction was added:

```
Loading all portfolios
   > Portfolio1 (ID: 1)
      > Coin1 (ID: 1)
         > Transaction1 (ID: 1, portfolioId=1, coinId=1)
   > Portfolio2 (ID: 2)
      > Coin1: (ID: 1)
```

The method starts working wrong when I am adding 2nd transaction for Portfolio 2 but the same Coin 1

```
Loading all portfolios
   > Portfolio1 (ID: 1)
      > Coin1 (ID: 1)
         > Transaction1 (ID: 1, portfolioId=1, coinId=1)
         > Transaction2 (ID: 2, portfolioId=2, coinId=1) < -- ! WRONG, THS WAS ADDED FOR Portfolio 2, SHOULD BOT BE HERE
   > Portfolio2 (ID: 2)
      > Coin1: (ID: 1)
         > Transaction1 (ID: 1, portfolioId=1, coinId=1) < -- ! WRONG, THS WAS ADDED FOR Portfolio 1, SHOULD BOT BE HERE
         > Transaction2 (ID: 2, portfolioId=2, coinId=1)
```

[image]

For each coin, I need to have only 1 unique transaction.

Comment: Why does `CoinWithTransactionsCrossRef` have `portfolioId`? This is a join table between `Coin` and `Transaction`. `Portfolio` does not seem to be involved. "each instance of the Coin entity corresponds to zero or more instances of the Transaction entity, and vice-versa" -- why does `TransactionEntity` have a `coinId`, as that represents either a 1:1 or 1:N relation?  "For each coin, I need to have only 1 unique transaction" -- that statement does not seem to agree with "each instance of the Coin entity corresponds to zero or more instances of the Transaction entity".

Comment: Hi @CommonsWare, maybe this is what I am doing wrong (but I don't know how to fix), actually in my case all transactions are unique and each `Coin` can have many `Transactions`, but `Transaction` can't have many `Coins`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I need to get on an object which contains Portfolio - > Coin -> and all Transactions which were added for that Portfolio and Coin, but I don't know how, I tried everything

Comment: @CommonsWare The point is `Portfolio1` and `Portfolio2` can contain `Coin1`, but `Coin1` inside `Portfolio2` should not have a transaction which I did for `Portfolio1`

Comment: "each Coin can have many Transactions, but Transaction can't have many Coins." -- that suggests that you do not need `CoinWithTransactionsCrossRef`, as that represents an M:N relation (coin with many transactions, transaction with many coins). "I don't know how to fix" -- it feels like you should revisit your entities and ensure that they correctly represent the nature of the relations between them. Get the data model right first, then worry about how to query for the portfolio->coin->transaction tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your issue may be that you are seeing too many relationships rather than taking a more hierarchical approach.

I suspect that A portfolio will implicitly contains coins. By implicitly that any coin in a portfolio will be in that portfolio because of a transaction and that a transaction is for a single coin. ​

> For each coin, I need to have only 1 unique transaction

If this is the case then there is no need for any cross reference tables.

Rather that may you just need:

- the 3 table/entities (portfolio, transaction and coin),
- a transaction with coin POJO

  - *(not even reuquired with what you have but I assume that Coin will eventually include more that just the coinId column)*.
- a second POJO that has the portfolio with the transaction with coin POJO.

So the first POJO, **TransactionWithCoin** could be :-

```
data class TransactionWithCoin(
    @Embedded
    val transactionEntity: TransactionEntity,
    @Relation(entityColumn = "coinId",parentColumn = "coinId")
    val coinEntity: CoinEntity
```

- note that this assumes that the CoinEntity will eventually have addition columns (otherwise this isn't need as you have the only column coinId in the Transaction)

The 2nd POJO **PortfolioWithTransactionWithCoin** *(should perhaps be an s between Transaction and WithCoin)* :-

```
data class PortfolioWithTransactionWithCoin (
    @Embedded
    val portfolioEntity: PortfolioEntity,
    @Relation(entity = TransactionEntity::class,parentColumn = "portfolioId",entityColumn = "portfolioId")
    val transactionWithCoinList: List<TransactionWithCoin>
)
```

The Dao for the above could be :-

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM portfolioEntity")
fun getPortfoliosWithTransactionsAndCoin(): List<PortfolioWithTransactionWithCoin>
```

- note tested for convenience and brevity on the main thread.

**Working Example**

I couldn't get all the transactions from the diagram. However this example does all but 1 (if a read the diagram correctly) My guess is that either portfolio 4 or 5 has a 2nd Coin2.

Anyway using the above with the following code in the MainActivity :-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var db: CoinDatabase
    lateinit var dao: AllDao
    val TAG: String = "COININFO"
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        /* Build the Database */
        db = Room.databaseBuilder(this,CoinDatabase::class.java,"coin.db")
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .build()
        dao = db.getAllDao()
        /* Insert 6 Portfolios */
        dao.insertPortfolio(PortfolioEntity(1,"Portfolio1"))
        dao.insertPortfolio(PortfolioEntity(2,"Portfolio2"))
        dao.insertPortfolio(PortfolioEntity(3,"Portfolio3"))
        dao.insertPortfolio(PortfolioEntity(4,"Portfolio4"))
        dao.insertPortfolio(PortfolioEntity(5,"Portfolio5"))
        dao.insertPortfolio(PortfolioEntity(6,"Portfolio6"))
        
        /* Insert 6 Coins */
        dao.insertCoin(CoinEntity("Coin1"))
        dao.insertCoin(CoinEntity("Coin2"))
        dao.insertCoin(CoinEntity("Coin3"))
        dao.insertCoin(CoinEntity("Coin4"))
        dao.insertCoin(CoinEntity("Coin5"))
        dao.insertCoin(CoinEntity("Coin6"))

        /*Insert the transactions */
        /* Portfolio 1 has 3 Transactions for Coin1, Coin4 and Coin6 */
        /* Portfolio 2* has no Transactions */
        /* Portfolio 3 has 1 Transactio for Coin 6*/
        /* Portfolio 4 has 2 Transactions for Coin 2 and Coin 6*/
        /* Portfolio 5 has 1 Transaction for Coin 2 */
        dao.insertTransaction(TransactionEntity("Trans1",1,"Coin1"))
        dao.insertTransaction(TransactionEntity("Trans2",5,"Coin2"))
        dao.insertTransaction(TransactionEntity("Trans3",4,"Coin2"))
        dao.insertTransaction(TransactionEntity("Trans4",3,"Coin6"))
        dao.insertTransaction(TransactionEntity("Trans6",1,"Coin4"))
        dao.insertTransaction(TransactionEntity("Trans7",1,"Coin6"))
        dao.insertTransaction(TransactionEntity("Trans8",4,"Coin6"))

        /* Extract all portfolios with transactions and thus the coins */
        var pwtac = dao.getPortfoliosWithTransactionsAndCoin()
        for(p: PortfolioWithTransactionWithCoin in pwtac) {
            logPortfolioWithTransactionsWithCoin(p)
        }
    }

    /* Functions for writing the data to the log */
    private fun logCoin(coin: CoinEntity) {
        Log.d(TAG,"\t\tCoinId = ${coin.coinId}")
    }
    private fun logTransaction(transaction: TransactionEntity) {
        Log.d(TAG,"\tTransactionId = ${transaction.transactionId} ParentPortfolioId = ${transaction.portfolioId} CoinId = ${transaction.coinId}" )
    }
    private fun logPortfolio(portfolioEntity: PortfolioEntity) {
        Log.d(TAG,"PortfolioName = ${portfolioEntity.name} ID = ${portfolioEntity.name}")
    }
    private fun logTransactionWithCoin(transactionWithCoin: TransactionWithCoin) {
        Log.d(TAG,"\tTransactionWithCoin:-")
        logTransaction(transactionWithCoin.transactionEntity)
        logCoin(transactionWithCoin.coinEntity)
    }
    private fun logPortfolioWithTransactionsWithCoin(portfolioWithTransactionWithCoin: PortfolioWithTransactionWithCoin) {
        Log.d(TAG,"PortfolioWithTransactionWithCoins:-")
        logPortfolio(portfolioWithTransactionWithCoin.portfolioEntity)
        for(transactionWithCoin: TransactionWithCoin in portfolioWithTransactionWithCoin.transactionWithCoinList) {
            logTransaction(transactionWithCoin.transactionEntity)
            logCoin(transactionWithCoin.coinEntity)
        }
    }
}
```

**The Result** *(as written to the Log)*

```
D/COININFO: PortfolioWithTransactionWithCoins:-
D/COININFO: PortfolioName = Portfolio1 ID = Portfolio1
D/COININFO:     TransactionId = Trans1 ParentPortfolioId = 1 CoinId = Coin1
D/COININFO:         CoinId = Coin1
D/COININFO:     TransactionId = Trans6 ParentPortfolioId = 1 CoinId = Coin4
D/COININFO:         CoinId = Coin4
D/COININFO:     TransactionId = Trans7 ParentPortfolioId = 1 CoinId = Coin6
D/COININFO:         CoinId = Coin6

D/COININFO: PortfolioWithTransactionWithCoins:-
D/COININFO: PortfolioName = Portfolio2 ID = Portfolio2

D/COININFO: PortfolioWithTransactionWithCoins:-
D/COININFO: PortfolioName = Portfolio3 ID = Portfolio3
D/COININFO:     TransactionId = Trans4 ParentPortfolioId = 3 CoinId = Coin6
D/COININFO:         CoinId = Coin6

D/COININFO: PortfolioWithTransactionWithCoins:-
D/COININFO: PortfolioName = Portfolio4 ID = Portfolio4
D/COININFO:     TransactionId = Trans3 ParentPortfolioId = 4 CoinId = Coin2
D/COININFO:         CoinId = Coin2
D/COININFO:     TransactionId = Trans8 ParentPortfolioId = 4 CoinId = Coin6
D/COININFO:         CoinId = Coin6

D/COININFO: PortfolioWithTransactionWithCoins:-
D/COININFO: PortfolioName = Portfolio5 ID = Portfolio5
D/COININFO:     TransactionId = Trans2 ParentPortfolioId = 5 CoinId = Coin2
D/COININFO:         CoinId = Coin2

D/COININFO: PortfolioWithTransactionWithCoins:-
D/COININFO: PortfolioName = Portfolio6 ID = Portfolio6
```